# Filtrar registros JSON por JavaScript ou PHP

Tags: php, jquery, query, filtro, indexof

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a como fazer filtragem de dados quando o cliente preenche um campo input. Estou buscando todos os registros do servidor (rodando PHP) através de uma solicitação JSON do jQuery e gostaria de saber como fazer um filtro menos "restritivo" por parte do JavaScript, visto que o método indexOf() retorna apenas registros referentes a valores digitados precisamente, mas quando realizo a busca diretamente por query o resultado é mais próximo do que preciso. Não quero usar querys ao BD com muita frequência por questões de performance.

Seguem o código javascript (onde pego o valor inserido pelo usuário, e faço o filtro nos registros JSON):

```
if( value.nome_produto.indexOf(busca) != -1 ){
    tr += `<tr class='_item_em_falta _tr_relative'>
        <td> ${value.registro} </td>
        <td> 
            <a href='detalhe.php?codigo=${value.produto_id}'>
                <img class='_minha_img' src='${value.imagem_pequeno}'>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='detalhe.php?codigo=${value.produto_id}'>
                ${value.nome_produto}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td> ${value.preco_produto} </td>
        <td> ${value.origem_produto} </td>
        <td> ${value.quantidade_total} </td>
        <td> ${value.quantidade_vendida} </td>
    </tr>`;
```

o filtro indexOf() usado acima apenas retorna os produtos com nome idêntico ao inserido pelo usuário (Case Sensitive e etc). gostaria de usar uma forma que permita filtrar os dados de uma forma menos restritiva (como o comando LIKE %exemplo% no MySQL)

Comment: Solicito realizar mais algumas edições na sua pergunta. Adicione exemplos de filtro menos "restritivo" e coloque também código que você tem feito.

Answer (score 0):

O `LIKE` do **MySQL** e o `indexOf` do **PHP** fazem um tipo de busca muito parecida. O que você pode fazer para resolver o seu problema de *Case Sensitive* no javascript, é igualar os valores. Ex:

```
var v1 = value.nome_produto.toUpperCase();
var v2 = busca.toUpperCase();

if( v1.indexOf(v2) != -1 ){
    tr += `<tr class='_item_em_falta _tr_relative'>
        <td> ${value.registro} </td>
        <td> 
            <a href='detalhe.php?codigo=${value.produto_id}'>
                <img class='_minha_img' src='${value.imagem_pequeno}'>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='detalhe.php?codigo=${value.produto_id}'>
                ${value.nome_produto}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td> ${value.preco_produto} </td>
        <td> ${value.origem_produto} </td>
        <td> ${value.quantidade_total} </td>
        <td> ${value.quantidade_vendida} </td>
    </tr>`;
```

Com isso ele retornará verdadeiro para uma comparação como: teste == TESTE!